# ASP.NET MVC - ViewModel is null when trying to post to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to send a ViewModel to a Controller using a form but when the method in the controller gets called, the ViewModel properties are all null.

Here is my VM:

```
 public class CheckoutViewModel
 {
     public Customer Customer { get; set; }

     public CreditCard CreditCard { get; set; }

     public ShippingAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }

 }
```

In my controller, I have two Checkout methods, one that accepts no parameters and one that accepts a `CheckoutViewModel`. Here are the signatures:

```
public IActionResult Checkout()
```

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Checkout(CheckoutViewModel checkoutViewModel)
```

In my `Checkout.cshtml`, my form looks like this:

```
 <form class="form-group" method="post" asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Checkout">
                <label asp-for="ShippingAddress.Address1"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="ShippingAddress.Address1" type="text" name="Address1" value="" />
                <label asp-for="ShippingAddress.Address2"></label>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="ShippingAddress.Address2" type="text" name="Address2" value="" />
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="ShippingAddress.City"></label>
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="ShippingAddress.City" type="text" name="City" value="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label asp-for="ShippingAddress.State"></label>
                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="ShippingAddress.State" type="text" name="State" value="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
/*
More inputs for CreditCard, etc...
*/
</form>
```

Any idea why all of the properties are null in my controller?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the Controller methods? (at least the signatures)

Comment: Maybe you don't have the `[FromBody]` parameter attribute?

Comment: @devNull Added to original question; also in the parameter-less method Checkout method, I am sending a `CheckoutViewModel` to the view with `Customer` and `ShoppingCartItems` already set; I am able to access these in the View, but are null as well after posting

Comment: The `asp-for` tag helpers should generate the `type`,  `name` and `value` elements. Maybe try removing those from your View, as they might be clashing with what the model binding is expecting

Comment: @devNull that can't be. I realized that he's binding the primitive types defined within each field of the ViewModel say e.g ShippingAddress.City where a city is a string. Otherwise it could've thrown an error.

Comment: @MosiaThabo I asked that because by default tag helpers will [generate a name for elements for child properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#navigating-child-properties). So in this case it would generate `name="ShippingAddress.City"`. But since OP is explicitly declaring `name="City"`, I thought that might be causing an issue with the model binding on the POST

Comment: @devNull Thank you so much! Removing those html attributes seemed to do the trick

Comment: @devNull So that worked for the properties where the user is inputting data, but for the properties that are getting initialized when the ViewModel is sent to the View (`Customer` and `ShoppingCartItems`), those are still null when getting sent to the controller. Do you know how to persist those values so they will be the same? Thanks!

Comment: @davidmoeller In order for the properties to bind to the model from the view, they need a corresponding input element. In that case, you can create hidden elements, with `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Name)` using HTML helpers, or `input asp-for="Customer.Name" type="hidden"` using tag helpers